# Pre-conditions and post-condition in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling

after all, we typically have to state what a function returns; that is, if we return a value from a function we are always making a promise about the return value (how else would a caller what to expect).

```
int area(int lenght, int width)
// pre-conditions : lenght and width are positive 
// post-condition : returns a positive value that is the area
{
if (lenght <= 0 || width <= 0) error("area() pre-condition"); 
int a = lenght * width; 
if (a <= 0) error("area() post-condition"); 
return a; 

}
```

This is a simple example of using pre-condition and post-condition, but what I can not understand is what the author says after showing the example:

> "We couldn't check the complete post-condition, but we checked the part that said that it should be positive".

What does it mean ? Why we couldn't check the complete post-condition ? In my understanding in this case as post-condition we just need to check that the variable a is positive, am I wrong ?

Than the author ask me this question :

> Find a pair of value so that the pre-condition of this version of area holds, but the post-condition doesn't.

Is it not impossible ??

Comment: Impossible from a mathematical perspective maybe, but C++ is far from mathematical.

Comment: Invalid Precondition / Valid Postcondition: -1 * -1 = .1 Valid Precondition / Invalid (undefined) Postcondition 2 * INT_MAX = ?

Answer (score 4):

> In my understanding in this case as post-condition we just need to check that the variable a is positive, am I wrong ?

Yes.  Note the full post-condition...

> returns a positive value **that is the area**

It's possible to pass values of `length` and `width` such that `a` does not come out to the correct area due to overflow.

Answer (score 3):

> Why we couldn't check the complete post-condition ?

Because part of the post-condition is "that is the area". We haven't checked that; and it's not trivial to check that the result of the multiplication is equal to the mathematically expected value.

> Is it not impossible ??

If the multiplication overflows, giving undefined behaviour, then you might get a negative result from two positive inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is most certainly about the signed arithmetic overflow in `lenght * width`.

In this case this is a very bad illustration of the notion of post-condition. The expectation that should be delineated to explain pre-conditions is:

- If the function is called with arguments that satisfy the pre-condition, then it does not invoke undefined behavior.
- If the function is called with arguments that satisfy the pre-condition, then the post-condition holds when the function terminates.

The example in your question illustrates the first point, not the second one.

The author thinks that the function returns a negative “area” for some input, but the author is wrong: the function can only return the correct result (a positive value that is the correct area) or invoke undefined behavior. That this undefined behavior can lead to `a` appearing negative on some compilation platforms is irrelevant. Undefined behavior is forbidden. Undefined behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: @SCFrench `lenght` is the name of the variable in the question. Pre- and post-conditions describe the content of the inputs and outputs of the function, not of hypothetical variables that would have the correct name for these.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is NOT forbidden. It is simply not defined by the Standard. The language translator can do anything in this case whilst remaining Standards Compliant. But that does not mean that it does, nor that code for which the Standard defines no requirements is wrong.  I write such code all the time because I know what the compiler does.

Comment: @Yttrill I don't see how this remark adds anything to this answer in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rectangle_area(int length, int width)
{
    // Pre-condition check
    if (length <= 0 || width <= 0)
        perror("area() pre-condition violated: length and width must be positive");

    int a = length * width;

    // Post-condition check
    if (a <= 0)
        perror("area() post-condition violated: the calculated area is not positive");

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int length = -5;
    int width  = -5;
    int result = rectangle_area(length, width);
    cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted violates the precondition, but the OP is looking for a case where the preconditions are satisfied but the postcondition is violated, so this is not really an answer. Also, code only answers tend to be downvoted. Please at least provide a few lines to explain your code next time.